Oracle Pro*C++. Fails with a "#if __has_include(<sys/single_threaded.h>)"
The context is a move to RHEL 9, with a new GNU compiler.  Some mucky old pro*c++ code fails to compile.  Googling and Copilot yielded nothing useful.  Likewise Oracle Support yielded nothing.
As I chopped away pieces, it got weird.  I'm looking for ideas on how to troubleshoot, or to maybe correct whatever is not not configured correctly.
Exhibit A is the file to compile.
#include <iostream>

int error_info
(
    void
)
{
    return -1;
}

Exhibit B is a test script that is used to do the compile.  Note that ORACLE_HOME is defined as /lx4051/app/oracle/product/19.3.0.
I empied the pcscfg.cfg file, so the script would define everything.
echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------- uname -s -r -v -m -p -i -o"
uname -s -r -v -m -p -i -o
echo " "

echo    "---------------------------------------------------------------------- Pro*C preprocess"
proc                                                                    \
        char_map=string                                                 \
        code=cpp                                                        \
        cpp_suffix=cpp                                                  \
        dynamic=ansi                                                    \
        hold_cursor=yes                                                 \
        lines=yes                                                       \
        lname=list.txt                                                  \
        ltype=long                                                      \
        maxopencursors=20                                               \
        prefetch=65535                                                  \
        release_cursor=no                                               \
        sqlcheck=full                                                   \
        userid=schema/password@instance                                 \
                                                                        \
        iname=error_info.pcpp                                           \
        oname=error_info.cxx                                            \
                                                                        \
        sys_include=/usr/include/c++/11                                 \
        sys_include=/usr/include                                        \
        sys_include=/lx4051/app/oracle/product/19.3.0/rdbms/public      \
        sys_include=/lx4051/app/oracle/product/19.3.0/precomp/public    \
        sys_include=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/11/include         \
        sys_include=/usr/include/c++/11/x86_64-redhat-linux             \
                                                                        \
            include=/usr/include/c++/11                                 \
            include=/usr/include                                        \
            include=/lx4051/app/oracle/product/19.3.0/rdbms/public      \
            include=/lx4051/app/oracle/product/19.3.0/precomp/public    \
            include=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/11/include         \
            include=/usr/include/c++/11/x86_64-redhat-linux             \

echo " "

Exhibit C is the output of script.
------------------------------------------------------------------------- uname -s -r -v -m -p -i -o
Linux 5.14.0-427.37.1.el9_4.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Sep 13 12:41:50 EDT 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

---------------------------------------------------------------------- Pro*C preprocess

Pro*C/C++: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Dec 16 11:51:08 2024
Version 19.24.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

System default option values taken from: /lx4051/app/oracle/product/19.3.0/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg

Syntax error at line 37, column 19, file /usr/include/c++/11/ext/atomicity.h:
Error at line 37, column 19 in file /usr/include/c++/11/ext/atomicity.h
#if __has_include(<sys/single_threaded.h>)
..................1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "<" when expecting one of the following:

   Message 117 not found;  product=precomp; facility=pcg

   Message 121 not found;  product=precomp; facility=pcg


Syntax error at line 34, column 1, file /usr/include/sys/single_threaded.h:
Error at line 34, column 1 in file /usr/include/sys/single_threaded.h
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "<eof>" when expecting one of the following:

   ( + - ~ ! DOUBLE_
   Message 117 not found;  product=precomp; facility=pcg

   Message 121 not found;  product=precomp; facility=pcg

The symbol "Message 117 not found;  product=precomp; facility=pcg
" was substituted for "<eof>" to continue.

Syntax error at line 37, column 39, file /usr/include/c++/11/ext/atomicity.h:
Error at line 37, column 39 in file /usr/include/c++/11/ext/atomicity.h
#if __has_include(<sys/single_threaded.h>)
......................................1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the following:

   ( * ? | & < > + - / % ^ || && == != <= >= << >>
The symbol "* was inserted before "." to continue.

Error at line 0, column 0 in file error_info.pcpp
PCC-F-02102, Fatal error while doing C preprocessing

What else can I do to troubleshoot this?
12/17/2024 - The short answer to the question is to prepare to submit a ticket to Oracle Support.  That rubber ducking process reminded me of another Pro*c rule of thumb.
Pro*c can't process some include files.  When it tries to ingest them there can be lots of warnings and errors.  Naturally iostream is one of these.
The standard method for supressing the problem is to surround the offending includes like this.
#ifndef ORA_PROC
    #include <iostream>
#endif

This ensures that pro*c won't see the include file, but the compiler will see it.  This solved my problem.
TIL:

In the change to RHEL9, and the new compiler, additional include files needed to be hidden this way.
It was not a configuration problem.


One notes that it is not finding the Oracle message files.

Not finding some error messages is odd. Are you sure the proc in your script is coming from the same ORACLE_HOME, not some rogue entry in your PATH?

Alex.  Running the same script, with the full path to the proc executable yields the same result.  The full path does match ORACLE_HOME.
